# LinqToExcel GetColumnNames at specific Row

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-excel

I am using the library LinqToExcel to read excel files in my mvc4 project. My problem is when I try to read the headers at row 4... How I can do this?

In project, exists a function that returns all the column names, but I suppose that the columns need to be at row 0.

```
    // Summary:
    //     Returns a list of columns names that a worksheet contains
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   worksheetName:
    //     Worksheet name to get the list of column names from
    public IEnumerable<string> GetColumnNames(string worksheetName);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the `GetColumnNames()` method only works when the header row is on row 1.

However, it should be possible to get the column names by using the `WorksheetRangeNoHeader()` method.

It would look something like this

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
// Only select the header row
var headerRow = from c in excel.WorksheetRangeNoHeader("A4", "Z4")
                select c;

var columnNames = new List<string>();
foreach (var headerCell in headerRow)
  columnNames.Add(headerCell.ToString());
```

Answer (score 6):

### An FYI for future googlers:

It appears that `GetColumnNames()` has changed since the above answer was accepted.

There is now an overload in which you can define the range of the header row as a string:

```
 // This will return a List<string> 
 var colNames = ExcelFile
                .GetColumnNames(SheetName, "A9:AF9")
                .ToList();
```