# C# LinqToExcel GetColumnName nth row

Tags: c#, excel, linq

I am trying to import the content of an excel sheet using LinqToExcel. I am now able to get the content but I need the header of the table. I was able to get the header of the table on a sheet if the header is on row 1 using this code:

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
var columnNames = excel.GetColumnNames("worksheetName");
```

The problem is in my current task, the header is in row 5, when I run my code, it gives back the content of row 1 as the header.

I can use the traditional import from excel command but it will be a longer code which we are trying to leverage Linq.

Any advise?

Comment: similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19359003/linqtoexcel-getcolumnnames-at-specific-row